# Problems with scale() and the Multidimensional Lp-Norm

Tags: r, distance, rcpp

Today I was trying to debug my code and stumbled across something that renders my solutions useless. What i am generally trying to calculate is the multidimensional L2-Norm for the following two matrices. As long as I am not using scale() everything is working fine. Nonetheless, as soon as I scale the matrices the solutions of the three used approaches are not the same anymore. What am I missing here?

```
set.seed(655)
df.a <- data.frame(A = sample(100:124, 24), B = sample(1:24, 24), C = sample(1:24, 24), D = rep(0, times=24))
df.b <- data.frame(A = sample(125:148, 24), B = sample(25:48, 24), C = sample(1:24, 24), D = sample(1:100, 24))
```

For this reason I have three different approaches:

1. sapply-function and sqrt of rowSums

   ```
   sse <-  function(x1, x2) sum((x1 - x2) ^ 2)

   distanceChangeByTech <- function(x) {
     sse(df.a[,x], df.b[,x])
   }
   help1 <- t(data.frame(sapply(colnames(df.a), distanceChangeByTech)))
   dist_sap <- sqrt(rowSums(help1))
   ```
2. multidimensional Euclidean distance using RCPP:

   ```
   multiEucl <- cxxfunction(signature(x="matrix", y="matrix"), plugin="Rcpp",
                     body='
                     Rcpp::NumericMatrix dx(x);
                     Rcpp::NumericMatrix dy(y);

                     const int N = dx.nrow();
                     const int M = dx.ncol();

                     double sum = 0;

                     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                     for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
                     sum = sum + pow(dx(i,j) - dy(i,j), 2);
                     }
                     }

                     return wrap(sqrt(sum));
                     ')
   ```
3. multidimensional Lp-Norm using RCPP:

   ```
   multiPNorm <- cxxfunction(signature(x="matrix", y="matrix", p="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp",
                     body='
                     Rcpp::NumericMatrix dx(x);
                     Rcpp::NumericMatrix dy(y);
                     double dp = Rcpp::as<double>(p);

                     const int N = dx.nrow();
                     const int M = dx.ncol();

                     double sum = 0;
                     double rsum = 0;

                     for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                     for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
                     sum = sum + pow(abs(dx(i,j) - dy(i,j)), dp);
                     }
                     }

                     rsum = pow(sum, 1/dp);
                     return wrap(rsum);
                     ')
   ```

When I tried this at first all worked well.

```
> multiEucl(as.matrix(df.a), as.matrix(df.b)) 
[1] 366.1543
> multiPNorm(as.matrix(df.a), as.matrix(df.b), 2) 
[1] 366.1543
> sqrt(rowSums(help1)) sapply.colnames.df.a...distanceChangeByTech. 
366.1543
```

But as soon as I scale the matrices, which I want to do because I will do a Clustering based on these distancemeasures, there is a fault. The solutions are not the same anymore?! What is causing this? I am using these commands to scale.

```
df.a <- as.data.frame(scale(df.a)) 
df.a[is.na(df.a)] <- 0
df.b <- as.data.frame(scale(df.b))
df.b[is.na(df.b)] <- 0

> multiEucl(as.matrix(df.a), as.matrix(df.b))
[1] 12.51781
> multiPNorm(as.matrix(df.a), as.matrix(df.b), 2)
[1] 8.944272
> sqrt(rowSums(help1))
sapply.colnames.df.a...distanceChangeByTech. 
                                    12.51781
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You used `abs()` which [is documented eg here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cstdlib/abs/) but you meant to use `fabs()` which is [documented here](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/cmath/fabs/).

The `cmath.h` header provides overloaded `abs()` as well, but you probably didn't include that.

Answer (score 0):

It seems that abs() is not doing the right thing here. Instead I changed my coding of the multiPNorm and the changes seem to work.

```
multiPNorm <- cxxfunction(signature(x="matrix", y="matrix", p="numeric"), plugin="Rcpp",
                      body='
                      Rcpp::NumericMatrix dx(x);
                      Rcpp::NumericMatrix dy(y);
                      double dp = Rcpp::as<double>(p);

                      const int N = dx.nrow();
                      const int M = dx.ncol();

                      double sum = 0;
                      double rsum = 0;
                      double help = 0;

                      for(int i=0; i<N; i++){
                      for(int j=0; j<M; j++){
                        help = dx(i,j) - dy(i,j);
                        if (help < 0) {
                          help = - help;
                        }
                        sum = sum + pow(help, dp);
                      }
                      }

                      rsum = pow(sum, 1/dp);
                      return wrap(rsum);
                      ')
```